# gradle errors in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

```
Error:(24, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
"openFile:/home/jeevansai/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle"
```

The above mentioned error is appearing in Android Studio has many issues making a project. Can someone tell a solution to it.

output of  `cat /home/jeevansai/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jeevansai.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    final def types = buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    types
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

output of `apt-cache policy junit4`

```
junit4:
  Installed: 4.12-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4.12-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4.12-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Post the contents of  your gradle file so we can see what it's trying to do, but there's a possible solution on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12)

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /home/jeevansai/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle`

Comment: sorry slow internet

Comment: intellij android studio , i did not do any configuration in it

Comment: Or someone provide me the link to download complete android sdk ,i mean all packages without the need for android studio to download.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is a build tool integrated in Android Studio: it downloads your project dependencies (the jar files you use in your code) from the maven repositories (maven is another well-known build tool with package dependencies capabilities and a remote ecosystem of repositories). One of the most used repository is **jcenter()**.

Your gradle file lack of a repository configuration: add this piece of code to your gradle file (`/home/jeevansai/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle`): between `apply plugin` and `android {...}` section.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
     jcenter()
}

android {
     compileSdkVersion 21
...
```

*Alternatively*, if you does not code the unit tests at the moment, you can simple comment out the junit dependency on the `app/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

*Anyhow*, you can always download the needed artifact from maven central and put in your `/libs` directory:

```
wget 'http://central.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar' -O /home/jeevansai/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/libs/junit-4.12.jar
```

Comment: not working same error shows up

Comment: I've accessed now a project created with Android Studio: can you paste the content of the *build.gradle* in the directory above *app*: ``/home/jeevansai/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/build.gradle``

Comment: I've updated my answer, waiting for your (project) root build.gradle, check if one of the solutions proposed works. The link to download the junit jar file can be found on a search engine of maven repos. I ofter use [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com)

Comment: I commented out the junit dependency and it works!